# Specify an additional plugin folder that's located in the local network

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I'm creating several plugins for an organization, that uses a local network to share workflow. But isn't a go choice install and upgrade the plugins for every coworker computer.

How could I create a folder into the network and then specify this path to QGIS? Is there any field to add complements folders such as exists for C++ complements?

Comment: Maybe you can create create a symbollink for every coworker computer,and only update the folder into network,or you can create your own plugins repository and only update this

Comment: How can I create a own plugins repository in QGIS?

Comment: Create your own and your clients connect to this https://github.com/All4Gis/CreateQgisRepository

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

Following the Frans's answer, I found a way to have just one folder with the complements.

I tried the method by creating the symbollink (soft link), but it didn't work in my test. So I tried to create a hard link. By this way it worked.

### Creating Hard Link

1. Open the Command Line as Adm.
2. Run the command:

```
mklink /J "path_to\python\plugins\link_name" "path\to\origin_folder"
```

Ref: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/